# excel vba to open a workbook by testing multiple passwords

Tags: vba, excel

I have password-protected .xls files in a directory. I would like to open each of these files and save them without the password.

However, the files can be opened by using either of the sample passwords listed below.

```
pwd1 = "123"
pwd2 = "456"
pwd3 = "789"

'Check if pwd1 opens
Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn, Password:=pwd1)

'If fail then use pwd2
Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn, Password:=pwd2)

'and so on..
```

How should I implement this?

Comment: What did you think of my answer?  Did it work, or was I wrong to assume you only needed the `Unprotect` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried @lebelinoz answer however the routine gives a 1004 error. I googled this behavior and found this post:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176638/vba-how-to-force-ignore-continue-past-1004-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176638/vba-how-to-force-ignore-continue-past-1004-error/)

The code below works by using `On Error Resume Next`. I based this on @lebelinoz answer.

```
Public Sub CrackWorkbook()
Dim fn As String
fn = "C:\Temp\test_password_is_456.xlsx"

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim item As Variant
Dim lst As Variant

lst = Array("123", "456", "789")

For Each item In lst
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn, Password:=item
If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo did_not_work:
    Exit For

did_not_work:
    Next item
Set wb = Activeworkbook
wb.SaveAs Filename:=fn, Password:=""
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer and I was able to (indirectly) help :)

Answer (score 2):

Once the file has been opened once, you only need to `Unprotect` it.  This will save a lot of time, instead of constantly opening/closing workbooks.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Public Sub CrackWorkbook()
    Dim fn As String
    fn = "C:\Temp\test_password_is_456.xlsx"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fn)

    Dim lst As Variant
    lst = Array("123", "456", "789")

    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In lst
        On Error GoTo did_not_work
        Call wb.Unprotect(item)
        Call wb.Save
        Call wb.Close(False)
        Exit Sub
did_not_work:
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next item
End Sub
```

In other words, create an array of strings and do a `For Each` on them, and set some error-handling to deal with all the failed attempts.

I know `GoTo` statements are a bit yucky, but that's the best way to handle errors in VBA (as far as I know).

Comment: I tried this however the routine gives a run-time error 1004 even after using the 'On Error' statement. I googled this behavior and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176638/vba-how-to-force-ignore-continue-past-1004-error

Comment: Thanks also for teaching me the .Unprotect method. Will be updating my code to use this, however for a quick solution I just used the opening and closing methods.