# vba move all docx extn files from folder to another

Tags: excel, vba

pls help.

i hve below code that move file from one folder to another..
but im getting error 'File not found' if there is no file in the sourcefolder.

How to change the code to continue and not to throw that error if file doesnt exist in source folder.
Also to move all files with .*docx extension in source folder.

```
Sub move_files()
Name "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter1\Q1.docx" As "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter1\backup\Q1.docx"
Name "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter2\Q2.docx" As "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter2\backup\Q2.docx"
Name "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3\Q3.docx" As "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter3\backup\Q3.docx"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this works (I have tested it) (I put the answer here to earn the points hehehehe)

```
Sub List_All_The_Files_Within_Path()

Dim File_Path As String
Dim File_Path2 As String
Dim str As String


File_Path = "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3"
File_Path2 = "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3\backup"

str = Dir(File_Path & "\*docx")

Do While str <> ""
Name File_Path & "\" & str As File_Path2 & "\" & str
str = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox "success"

End Sub
```

The best of all is that it ain't throe an error if it doesn't find any .docx file

Comment: yeah it works thts great :) thxs 1 point 4 u :).. Is it possible that in the excel sheet ColA2 is sourcepath & colB2 is destination path instead to hardcode it.. how to amend?

Comment: i will have several quarter 1, quarter 2 folders path & files to move hw u suggest to do it pls..? im new to vba & excel stuffs question might be silly....

Comment: It depends on how many paths will you use. If those paths are near to your workbook, you can use `str = ThisWorkBook.Path` and after you add other features with & (ampersand for concatenating). For example `str&"/subfolder"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

On Error Resume Next

' ...code that get error

On Error Goto 0

This topc explain well the argument.

[vba - how to force ignore/continue past 1004 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176638/vba-how-to-force-ignore-continue-past-1004-error)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the error part, it is as simple to write

```
On Error Resume Next
```

At the beggining of the sub

for getting only files .docx it depends on what SO you are working on. Remember that VBA for windows is different than for Mac, here is a code for windows that you can use (I haven´t tried it yet)

```
Sub List_All_The_Files_Within_Path()


Dim No_Of_Files As Integer    
Dim File_Path1 As String
Dim File_Path2 As String    

File_Path = "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3"
File_Path2 = "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3\backup"



'Lists all the files in the current directory

With Application.FileSearch
.NewSearch
.LookIn = File_Path
.Filename = "*.docx"
.SearchSubFolders = False
.Execute

No_Of_Files = .FoundFiles.Count

For i = 1 To No_Of_Files
   Name File_Path &.FoundFiles(i).Name  As File_Path2 &.FoundFiles(i).Name

Next i

End With

End Sub
```

try it on and tell me if it worked

Comment: using windows office.. Got compile error "invalid qualifier" when click on debug it point to .FoundFiles line                                              
Name File_Path & .FoundFiles(i).Name As File_Path2 & .FoundFiles(i).Name

Comment: The problem was that that function was removed form vba since 2010 (As I got). Look at my newest answer to find the code suited for you

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if the source file exists, and move it if it does...

```
Sub move_files()
    MoveIfExists "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter1\Q1.docx", "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter1\backup\Q1.docx"
    MoveIfExists "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter2\Q2.docx", "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter2\backup\Q2.docx"
    MoveIfExists "D:\cashflow\WIP\quarter3\Q3.docx", "D:\cashflow\CPL\quarter3\backup\Q3.docx"
End Sub

Sub MoveIfExists(src as string, dest as string)
    If Len(Dir(src)) > 0 Then
        Name src As dest
    End If
End sub
```